# Exclude a post deployment script in Visual Studio 2013 SQL Server project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sqlcmd, sqlproj

Exclude a post deployment script in Visual studio 2013 SQL Server project. I am not explaining the whole requirement why I have to do this. I am explaining part of my issue; please bear it.

I have the following script:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [College]

CREATE TABLE [College].[Department]
(
    [Name] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
)
```

In a post deployment script I have a script file which is not included in the build, and I am inserting a value in the department table:

```
INSERT INTO [College].[Department]
 ([DeptId], [DeptName])
 Values('77ACE81C-7C41-4A31-8F39-9814E36548A1', 'Computer')
```

As my department table doesn't have Department Id, I want to exclude this script, so based on a condition I am including this file by taking the help of a command-line variable. My post deployment file has the following entry:

```
IF('$(UseDepartMent)' = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Command Line UseDepartment is 1'
    :r .\Script.DepartMentTableEntry.sql
END
GO
```

> (90,1): SQL72014: .NET SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 47 Invalid column name 'DeptId'.

Comment: If you right click on the file and go to properties, what is the Build Action set to?

Comment: @EdElliott It is set to None